# Google Visualization throws "Invalid JSON string" in chrome extension with manifest v2

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-visualization

Since Google is pushing us to use manifest v2 with all its security stuff in Chrome extensions, I cannot use Google Visualization (its graphs specifically), because of error "Invalid JSON string". I believe it must be another bug, but the error message is just wrong.

According to [Visualization API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw), second parameter is optional, but when I don't pass it to the draw method, the error goes *Invalid JSON string: "{}"*. Otherwise whole JSON options object is printed as invalid, so there is definetely no error in it. If you have any more doubts about it - it works with no problems with manifest v2.

I've also tried to sandbox html file that loads Visualization API and tries to draw the graph in iframe, but after hours of trial-error approach when I finnaly managed to get it going, there was another error thrown saying "You browser does not support graphs.". This explains more than enough :), but being curious programmer as I am, I looked into devtools console to see an error message "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL..." and I gave up.

If you have any thoughts and ideas about this issue, please share them with me.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as you. Did you find a way to succeed?

Comment: @dskang's answer below resolved it for me.  I was having the same problem on a site (not extension) with a content security policy set.  Normally the browser reports violations in the console logs, but it didn't in this case; I just had the charts API failing to load a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by adding 'unsafe-eval' to your security policy.

e.g. `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the root of the problem is the Chrome security policy which disallows some features that Visualisation code uses, such as eval() and inline onload handlers for iframes. See http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=978.